# Consider the following elliptical problem on the disk

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the following elliptical problem on the disk:
\begin{cases} 
      \Delta u(x,y)=y, & x^2+y^2<4 \\
      u|_{r=2}=\sin(\theta). &  
   \end{cases}
Is considered the following indication: we consider $\bar{u}=\frac{1}{6}y^3.$

I understood that if we have an nonhomogeneous equation we must look for a solution of form: $u=\bar{u}+v$, where $v$ is determined in this way:
\begin{cases} 
      \Delta v(x,y)=0, & x^2+y^2<4 \\
      v|_{r=2}=\sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{6}y^3. &  
   \end{cases}
I can't understand where that expression came from for $\bar{u}.$ The solution for $v$ will be determined using the variable separation method, but I do not know how the other solution was considered.
I would like to know, just for the moment when I should find out, without having this indication in the requirement.
I think this solution is considered because it checks the equation: $\Delta u=y.$
I hope what I found is good.
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like they just found the solution of the non-homogeneous part by $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = y$ and supposing that $u = ay^3$. From this you will find that $a = 1/6$